# DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.TokenEndpointProtocolException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

We are implementing an IAuthorizationServerHost to accommodate OAuth2 functionality for our group of sites.

I am using the DontNetOpenAuth 0.25 package having upgraded from the 0.23 package which has required some changes that required some code changes.

during the AuthorizationServer.HandleTokenRequest() call i am getting the following

> DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth: 2012-08-24T18:06:55 ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth -
>   Client credentials grant access request for client
>   "********OMITTED********" rejected by authorization server host. A
>   first chance exception of type
>   'DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.TokenEndpointProtocolException' occurred in
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationServer.dll
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel: 2012-08-24T18:06:55 DEBUG
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Preparing to send
>   AccessTokenFailedResponse (2.0) message.
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings: 2012-08-24T18:06:55 DEBUG
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ChannelElements.MessageValidationBindingElement
>   did not apply to message. DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings:
>   2012-08-24T18:06:55 DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding
>   element
>   DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ChannelElements.TokenCodeSerializationBindingElement
>   did not apply to message. DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel:
>   2012-08-24T18:06:55 INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared
>   outgoing AccessTokenFailedResponse (2.0) message for : 
>     error: unauthorized_client
>
> DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel: 2012-08-24T18:06:55 DEBUG
>   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Sending message:
>   AccessTokenFailedResponse

I can confirm that the client_id is correct.

Has anyone got some advise or experience with this issue?

I have tried manually creating the requests with chrome's REST console and am having the same results.

some code snippets as requested (altered to protect the innocent)

//client side

```
public class MyOAuth2Client : OAuth2Client
{
 ...
}
```

the above class is registered as a client in the MVC4 AuthConfig.cs

the function QueryAccessToken is over-ridden and i use a WebServerClient object from the DotNetOpenAuth lib to construct a request. MyWebServerClient.GetClientAccessToken();

//Server side

I have implemented the IAuthorizationServerHost interface and construct an authorization server;

```
AuthorizationServer _authorizationServer = new AuthorizationServer( new     OAuth2AuthorizationServerHost() );
```

the token query is handled via

```
public ActionResult Token()
{
  _authorizationServer.HandleTokenRequest( Request ).AsActionResult();
}
```

Comment: Hi, please add your code to your question.